# How do I export diagram as image format with mathematical typesetting?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

When I export diagram with mathematical typesetting, the diagram shows the LaTeX command instead. Is this a bug, or is there some setting that I'm unaware of to fix this problem?

Here is an illustration of what I meant.

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known issue at the time of posting, it is now resolved.